# SharePoint Foundation 2013 basic Question

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I install SharePoint Foundation 2013. Can I create different site WebApplication and Site Collection for Team Site as we can create in SharePoint Enterprise.

Can I use SharePoint Designer for Workflow & Task List for Project Management in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

Is it possible to do custom coding using object model visual studio and deploy on SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do all the things you mentioned.

The main features that are missing in Foundation are Social, Fast Search/Continuous Crawl, Content Management, BI, Design Manager etc.

You can get a quick look on feature comparison [here](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-foundation-server/)